# Vertically center items with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to vertically center items with CSS' flexbox; and, I know how to do it with the non-vendor-prefixed code, but even with the vendor prefixes I can't get it to work in Webkit (Chrome).

I am trying to vertically align the spans in #trigger.

Here is my CSS:

```
#trigger{
    /* 2009 syntax */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: box;
    /* current syntax */
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

#trigger span{
    /* 2009 syntax */
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    /* current syntax */
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    flex-align: center;
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

And if you know the other vendor prefixes / versions of the properties that I am using, feel free to share them so that this can work in more than just Webkit.

Comment: This might come in handy:  https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/727c9d558b374d27c5b6

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `align-items` property is for *flex containers* (elements with `display: flex` applied to them), not *flex items* (children of *flex containers*).  The old 2009 spec does not have a property comparable to `align-items`; the `box-align` property from 2009 matches up to `align-content` from the standard spec.

http://jsfiddle.net/mnM5j/2/

```
#trigger {
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10em;
  background: yellow;
}

<div id="trigger">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus porta elit vel ante hendrerit facilisis. Curabitur aliquam sollicitudin diam, id posuere elit consectetur nec.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Here's a demo that demonstrates vertical/horizontal centering with anonymous flex items:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/mxuFa

Comment: Thank you, the demo works perfectly, but when I try to apply it to my code it doesn't work.
Would you mind taking a look at the css for #trigger and #trigger span that I have ?

Comment: Which demo?  For the one on codepen, #trigger would to the ul and the span would correspond to the li.  If that doesn't solve it, provide a demo so I can see the problem.

Comment: the js fiddle works perfectly. Oh, now it is working. Maybe it was too late last night when I was trying to implement it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 9):

A vertically aligned layout can be achieved with following properties, please note that this is using the old syntax, though I've tested on latest builds of Chrome, Firefox & Firefox Aurora -

```
#trigger {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;

  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;

  display: -moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;

  display: box;
  box-orient: vertical;
  box-pack: center;
  box-align: center;
}

#trigger span {
  display: block;
}
```

`box-orient` specifies how the box's children should be aligned, which in our case is vertical.

`box-pack` aligns the children along the box-orient axis.

`box-align` aligns the children inside the box, it's axis is perpendicular to the box-orient axis, i.e. in our case since the box-orientation is vertical, it'll decide the alignment of the children horizontally.

Here's a [Codepen demonstration](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lymle), the properties I've applied on span elements other than `display: block` are purely for cosmetic purposes.

Comment: Using `box-pack`/`justify-content` for vertical centering *only* works when the flex alignment is column/vertical, not row/horizontal.  If the OP wants the elements laid out horizontally, heights must be implied on the flex items and wrapping enabled.  As far as I can tell, browsers that only implement the old 2009 spec do not support wrapping at all.

Comment: You're right, but as stated in the question OP was in fact trying to 'vertically' align the spans in #trigger, hence I saw the above implementation fit for the use case.

Comment: You are using older and much slower prefixes by the way, the new one is display: flex

Comment: yes, this was using the old syntax, as mentioned in my answer above.