# how to vertically align figcaption to img in figure

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, figure

How do you vertically align the text of the figcaption to the image in this figure.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/YdATG/1/

HTML

```
<section class="links">
   <a href="#">
    <figure class="grid-parent clearfix">
            <figcaption class="grid-80 push-20 fontEmphazie">foo</figcaption>
            <img alt="Foto" src="http://www.google.com/intl/de/homepage/images/google_favicon_64.png" class="grid-20 pull-80 grid-no-pad-left grid-no-pad-right">
    </figure>
   </a>
   <a href="#">
    <figure class="grid-parent clearfix">
                <figcaption class="grid-80 push-20 fontEmphazie">bar</figcaption>
                <img alt="Foto" src="http://www.google.com/intl/de/homepage/images/google_favicon_64.png" class="grid-20 pull-80 grid-no-pad-left grid-no-pad-right">
    </figure>
   </a>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section.links figure, section.links figure {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

section.links figure {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

section.links figcaption, section.links figcaption {
    padding: 0 0.5em;
}

section.links a, section.links a {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: why not use flexbox?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726740/vertically-centre-items-with-flexbox

Comment: http://caniuse.com/flexbox ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say

```
figure {
    display: table;
}

figure a {
    display: table-cell;
}

figcaption {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Assuming that the image determines the size of the link.

Comment: I misplaced the ankor in the first fiddle, sorry

Comment: okay this works partially, but now everything is not responsive anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/YdATG/7/ ... ah I don't get this table stuff :/

Comment: vertical-align is meant to be used in table (and maybe in some other things), that's what you must make parent elements as tables and table cells.

Comment: there is acutally another table already around it, but that does not seem to be a problem, I just do not figure how to get it to full width: http://jsfiddle.net/YdATG/8/

otherwise your answer would be the best one

Comment: Table cells are a pain in the ass though. Have you tried width: 100%; ?

Comment: If your content has a fixed height you can also position it at 50% from top with a negative margin of half its height and drop all the table-related styling.