# Center div vertically in flexbox container with stretch alignment

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to center a div in flex container with keeping the height of the whole container for that div. Obviously, I have `align-items:stretch` for keeping a height or `align-items:center` for centering block. What is a good approach for flexbox model to center a div with keeping height of the parent container?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/symb8s02/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could wrap the text node with a `span` element and then set the `display` of `.child2` to `flex` and add `align-self: center` to the child `span` element for vertical centering.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrkzw8jb/)

```
.child2 {
    border-left: 1px black solid;
    align-self: stretch;
    display: flex;
}
.child2 > span {
    align-self: center;
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.child1 {
    background-color: green;
}

.child2 {
    border-left: 1px black solid;
    align-self: stretch;
    display: flex;
}
.child2 > span {
    align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="child1">
        <h1>Text</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        <span>should be centered vertically</span>
    </div>
</div>
```