# Vertically align the text of an input element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I've had a bit of an issue with some flex containers. They're a label and an input in a flex container. Unfortunately, if I change the height of the container from auto, the contents cease aligning - the label's text remains at the start of the flexbox, but the input's text follows the middle. I've written a MWE to demonstrate.

```css
label, input {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: black;
}

.stretch {
  display:flex;
  height: 4em;
}
.baseline {
  display: flex;
  height: 4em;
  align-content: baseline;
}
.flex-innards {
  display: flex;
  height: 4em;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.flex-innards * {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.flex-innards-start {
  display: flex;
  height: 4em;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.flex-innards-start * {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.short {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="stretch">
  <label>Stretch alignment</label>
  <input value=":("></input>
</div>

<div class="baseline">
  <label>How about baseline?</label>
  <input value=">:("></input>
</div>

<div class="flex-innards">
  <label>Flexing the children kinda works</label>
  <input value=":o"></input>
</div>

<div class="flex-innards-start">
  <label>But only if they're centered</label>
  <input value=":("></input>
</div>

<div class="field short">
  <label>Deceptive stretch</label>
  <input value=":S"></input>
</div>
```

https://jsbin.com/nulobolulo/edit?html,css,output.

I've managed to make them vertically centered together in the third box there (using [How to vertically align and stretch content using CSS flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063770/how-to-vertically-align-and-stretch-content-using-css-flexbox)), but I'd like to have them both have their text aligned to flex-start, as well as filling the complete height of their container.

If possible, I'd like to avoid adding extra elements to the HTML. Thank you.

Comment: Side note: No closing tags required on `<input>` elements.

Comment: yes `<input>` is an empty tag. to be specific it doesnt even have a closing tag nor does it have a slash at the end since HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to address this problem with CSS uses the `padding` property.

```css
input {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

label,
input {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
}

.stretch {
  display: flex;
  height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="stretch">
  <label>Stretch alignment</label>
  <input value=":(">
</div>
```

Comment: Ah that's rough - it'd be great if flexboxes would allow this naturally, without much brittleness. I'll wait a bit to see if there's some voodoo someone has up their sleeve for it.

Comment: It's not a flexbox issue. `input` elements don't recognize flex layout.