# How to vertically align content in Css 3 using flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I've aligned my content vertically through many different ways but i wanna know that how can i vertically align my content using flexbox in Css3

Comment: Please try to learn the concepts of flexbox. A `display: flex` and `justify-content: centre` will help you to get this done. Have you tried out the same? If you are facing issue even after adding these, please post your relavent code so that someone could debug your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertically center items with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726740/vertically-center-items-with-flexbox)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily vertically align content by placing the content inside a div. And give  **"display:flex"** property to that div. And for horizontal alignment, you can use **"justify-content"** property on that div. And for vertical alignment, you can use **"align-items"** property on that div. Plus there is one more property **align-content** to align the flex lines.

**Note that:**

**1.** Justify-content and align-items properties only work when display is flex.

**2.** Remember that, without enough height, you will not see any change in the vertical alignment. So, first give some height to div. Same goes for width, if your div have not empty space around, you will not feel any change in horizontal Alignment. Although, alignment is set. But as content cover the whole space inside div. So, you will not feel any alignment.

**3.** There is a case of flex-direction. If flex-direction change to column, then you will see that align-items property is used to set the horizontal alignment. Similarly, in this case, Justify-content property is used to set the vertical alignment.

Moreover, there is also **align-self** property that works with child Elements. If you want to give some different vertical alignment to any child of that div. You can use align-self property with that child element.

Comment: The direction of justify-content and align-items change depending on the flex-direction

Comment: Yes, I know but the question is not about flex-direction case. The person asks only about alignment. It is obvious that when you alter the flex-direction, it effects the flexbox. But that was not the question here. Please Read Question first.

Comment: Aligning the content vertically with flexbox depends directly on the direction of the flex, so saying that align-items aligns them vertically is not exactly correct.

Comment: Oky. I edited my answer. And mentioned about flex direction. Thanks for Guiding.